# Calculating hours worked

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to answer this question

> Prompt the user to enter the day, start hour, finish hour and
>   calculate the number of hours worked (e.g. 9 to 11 is 2 hours). NOTE:
>   You are not required to consider minutes. Display the information
>   entered and the number of hours worked back to the screen.

This is the answer I have developed so far

Pseudo-code

- Prompt user/admin to enter what day it is
- Prompt user/admin to enter the hour they start work
- Prompt user/admin to enter the hour they finish work
- Calculate the number of hours the user works for that day
- Print the information entered, as well as the number of hours worked back to the screen

```
<script language ="JavaScript">

adminday = prompt("Enter todays day");    //user types in the day
adminstart = number=parseInt(prompt("enter the hour you started"));    //user types in the hour they started
adminfinish = number=parseInt(prompt("enter the hour you finish"));    //user types in the hour they finished
document.write("The day you entered was", adminday, "<br>");
document.write("The hour you started was", adminstart, "<br>");
document.write("The hour you finished was", adminfinish, "<br>");
hoursworked = (adminstart+adminfinish);    //adds up the users input for the hour they started and finished
document.write("The number of hours you worked were", hoursworked,  "<br>");    //displays the number of hours worked

</script>
```

I am confused over how to calculate the hours worked and I am not sure if it should be an addiction should it be a subtraction?

Comment: ...you already explained that from 9 to 11 is 2, so the algorithm is quite clear in your mind.

Comment: Definitely shouldn't be an addiction.

Comment: Unrelated, but you'll need a different way to add newlines in your HTML besides syntactically-invalid JS. Also, `adminstart = number = parseInt(...)` seems like an assign too many.

Comment: How much longer do you have on your test?

Comment: @TravisJ What about from 9 to 1?

Comment: FYI: `<script language ="JavaScript">` is deprecated, it's `<script type="text/javascript">` or just `<script>`.  Also it's bad practice to use `document.write`.  You should use `.innerHTML` to write to an element (eg: `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'your string';`).

Comment: Apparently there *was* some confusion, based on the last sentence of the OP. (The second number *can* be lower, since the text field is free-form, so it must be accounted for. It appears you know how to do that, but it wasn't immediately clear, again from that last sentence of the OP. Sorry.)

Comment: Is this question a joke? Don't they teach simple arithmetic in 1st grade any more?

Comment: @Barmar Hence my confusion :/ Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this as you must be using a 24 hour clock as you dont ask anything about AM or PM

```
adminstart = 10;
adminfinish = 18;

hoursworked = (adminfinish - adminstart);
```

hoursworked would be 8